# Regex based String modification

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to modify a string using REGEX in js that too in two ways

1)  Operators(AND|OR) in string must have a leading and trailing whitespace ie if say string is

`(C1 AND C2 ORC3) AND (C4OR C5)` then must be modified to `(C1 AND C2 OR C3) AND (C4 OR C5)`

2)  parenthesis must not have whitespace in between them and also with conditions(Cn) ie

`( ( C1 AND C2 OR C3) ) AND (  C4 OR C5)` then it must be modified to `((C1 AND C2 OR C3)) AND (C4 OR C5)`

Comment: operators used are only AND|OR .. nd nothing else also parenthesis are also to be only () .. no square brackets or anythin else will be there in string

Comment: What's the issue you are having? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Is there a problem if AND/OR are separated by two spaces rather than just one?

Comment: i need a simple regex to staisfy the condition .. @RohitJain is ques not clear enough ..

Comment: @ExplosionPills if that is the case i can trim down the multiple whitespaces with single whitespace later on..  ;)

Comment: @Garry, your question is very clear, but we like to see some effort from your side and not just a "these are my requirements, give me a solution" (aka Gimme teh codez) question. We love to help with problems, but we don't want to do your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this :

```
var str = .replace(/(AND|OR)(\w)/g, "$1 $2")
          .replace(/(\w)(AND|OR)/g, "$1 $2")
          .replace(/\(\s/g, "(")
          .replace(/\s\)/g, ")");
```

It changes

```
"( ( C1 AND C2 ORC3 ) ) AND ( C4 ORC5)"
```

to

```
"((C1 AND C2 OR C3)) AND (C4 OR C5)"
```

It could be made shorter but would lose readability.

Answer (score 2):

I wont write a single code. But the idea will give you the solution with a little php knowledge.

- replace all `AND` and `OR` with `<space>AND<space>` and `<space>OR<space>` Look carefully the second version have white spaces around them.
- replace all double white space with single one. Loop through this rule untill there is no double white space.
- replace `(<space>` with `(` and `<space>)` with `)`. Again looks carefully

`<space>` means white space here.

Answer (score 1):

```
.replace(/\s*([()])\s*/g, "$1")
.replace(/AND|OR/g, " $& ")
.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

This works properly on your last test string.  It should account for more than one space separating parentheses and even trims extra space.

Answer (score 0):

```
function attempt(str){
   return str.replace(/\s/g,"").replace(/(AND|OR)/g," $1 ");
}
function test(){
    var str = '( ( C1ANDC2 OR C3)          ) AND     ( C4  ORC5)',
        expected = '((C1 AND C2 OR C3)) AND (C4 OR C5)';
    return attempt(str) ===  expected;
}
```